# how do we put jquery date picker in chrome extension

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework, google-chrome-extension, datepicker

I am implementing google chrome extension. I have written the following code for the same.

```
var callback = document.getElementById('callback');
 callback.addEventListener('click', function() {
     datepicker({"readonly":true,"changeYear":true,"changeMonth":true,"dateFormat":"yy-mm-dd","numberOfMonths":3,"required":false});
    });
```

but the above code is not working. if anyone know the right way, please suggest me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Arjun's answer:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

it didnt worked, so I down-graded the jquery-1.9.1.js to lower version and it worked like charm. So change your jquery min version, it will start working.

Degrade the jquery.min file to lower version and enjoy. Tested, its working successfully with 1.8 version :)